# Why can't the PIC18 perform a divide operation accurately?

Tags: pic, gps

I just noticed that when I am converting coordinates from N/S E/W format to decimal format it getting wrong product. I tested 1256/3600 which should be 0.3488888888889 but my pic gives me 0.3488922 and 7/60 which should be 0.11666666666 and pic gives me 0.116666794. When adding those products and the number 23 I get 23.46582 but it should be 23.4655555556. As I am building a laptimer I do not want this much error.
According to http://www.sunearthtools.com/dp/tools/conversion.php I need 0.00001 precision which is 1.11 meters. I could tolarate a bit more but not much more. I could give a guess that this is because of the processor but I really think it should be a way around it.

The formula I am using is: x + y / 60 + z/3600 where x,y,z are integers.

Comment: And how are you actually getting position data that precise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some compilers for the PIC have an option to select either a 24-bit or 32-bit floating-point format.  You don't specify your compiler or its settings, but I would guess you're set to use less precise math.  Note, BTW, that floating-point division is apt to be much slower than multiplication.  Pre-computing the values of 1/60.0 and 1/3600.0 and multiplying by those is apt to be much faster than dividing by 60.0 or 3600.0.

Comment: Thank you, I am using the XC8 compilator with just standard settings.

Comment: Tested it and got much better results!

Answer (score 1):

Because of floating point formats, numbers are not exact.
If you need that precision, use fixed point math.

[What every computer scientist should know about floating point math.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) by David Goldberg, 1991

Comment: Thank you, I tested some more before I saw your answer and if I make the numbers 10'000 times larger, I got better result. Is this something I could do if I dont want to go all the way with the fixed point math or was it just a coincidence?

Comment: Even so, 32 bit floats should be able to provide the desired accuracy.

Comment: Floating point formats are exact.  It is the _operations_ like `+`, `/`, etc. that generate results that differ from math that are "inexact".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your compiler. One of your numbers (1256/3600) appears to be calculated to 5 digit precision (about 16 bits) and the other (7/60) to about 24 bit precision, implying mixed 24 and 32 bit math (with one byte used for the exponent).

Using 32-bit floating point math should be good enough for you (perhaps called doubles with your compiler). Some compilers have 64-bit doubles, which is more than good enough (but slower).